# Linq.dynamic.core IQueryable to SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm currently using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` to generate the SQL statements in my application. The problem is when I tried

```
db.table.select("new (column1 as a1)").ToString()
```

The generated SQL string is automatically adding another `1 AS [C1]` & the column alias `a1` didn't show up in the output string:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1],
    [Extent1].[column1] AS [column1]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [table].[column1] AS [column1]
     FROM 
         table AS [table]) AS [Extent1]
```

My question is how to achieve below outcome & why above behaviour happening.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[column1] AS [c1]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [table].[column1] AS [column1]
     FROM 
         table AS [table]) AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: After a long search, i realized it's a painful job to achieve above results using `LINQ` & it look likes the final purpose of `LINQ` are dealing with the `List object` will be returned. So i decided to use the sql builder library `https://sqlkata.com/` to generate the desired queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line of code that gets data to

```
var list = db.table.Select("new (column1 as a1)").ToDynamicList();
```

The result will be `List<dynamic>` of dynamic objects that each have `a1` property.

The actual SQL statement may differ, but the name of the property returned will respect the alias name.

Comment: Hi Martin, my intention is retrieving the SQL statement generated by LINQ behind the scene & pass this string to the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` for line-by-line processing. I'm aware of `ToDynamicList()` will return the List object with correct column's names. So the question is still remain `"Will it possible to tell LINQ to generate the SQL statement with the correct column alias ?"`

Comment: imho it would be easier and safe to rely on your own sql statements, the statements generated by entity framework may change from version to version. In my test with EF Core, the statements looked different from those you posted in the question.

Comment: Thanks Martin, from your advise, i decided to adopt the `sqlTaka` library to generate my own queries & control the performance of SQL statement (it look likes the queries generated by `LINQ` has some performance troubles if queries become complex due to a lot of wrapped queries). But it's good to know why `LINQ` generated the weird column `1 AS [C1]`